# LinearRing with direction KML

Tags: php, kml

I have a database with points (coordinates) and headings (direction/azimuths). I would like to create pie shaped sectors(LinearRing) pointing in the headings direction in kml. Anyone has any suggestions on how to build this using php?

Comment: Could your please specify "pie shaped sectors"? A simple sketch of how this should look like would be just fine. The rest is simple geometry ...

Comment: I have uploaded a pie shape manually created https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B0rMch-nfpzmcE8taU9pb0xJQ00

Comment: The opening angle is const / pre-set for all?

Comment: opening angle would depend on headings (direction/azimuths) for the point

Answer (score 0):

Ok, php is not my strength. Here is pseudo-code, which might help you (*).

"On a sphere of radius r, compute points on a great circle at specified azimuths and ranges.  PHI, LAMBDA, PHI0, LAMBDA0, and AZ are angles in radians, and RNG is a distance having the same units as R."

```
INPUT: phi0, lambda0, az, rng, r
OUTPUT: phi,lambda 

rng = rng / r; // Convert the range to an angle on the sphere (in radians).

epsilon = 1.7453e-07; // Set tolerance
if(phi0 >= pi / 2 - epsilon) // starting at north pole
    az = pi; 
if(phi0 <= epsilon - pi / 2) // starting at south pole
    az = 0; 

// Calculate coordinates of great circle end point using spherical trig.
phi = asin( sin(phi0) * cos(rng) + cos(phi0) * sin(rng) * cos(az) );

lambda = lambda0 + atan2( sin(rng) * sin(az) , cos(phi0) * cos(rng) - sin(phi0) * sin(rng) * cos(az) );
```

*phi0* and *lambda0* are your initial coordinates and *az* your heading. Vary *az* +/- a certain range in order to obtain points, which form the circle segment of the pie. The rest should be straight-forward.

(*) Source: http://mind.cog.jhu.edu/courses/680/octave/Installers/Octave/Octave.OSX10.6/Applications/MATLAB_R2009b.app/toolbox/map/map/private/greatcirclefwd.m